# Why does each OpenSharedResource call cause the video memory to increase (leak)?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I have a simple cross-thread (ID3D11Device) program, and found that OpenSharedResource has a serious video memory leak: every time OnTimer has a few megabytes of video memory increase. and checked the post [DirectX 9 to 11 OpenSharedResource is leaking memory like crazy. Am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428682/directx-9-to-11-opensharedresource-is-leaking-memory-like-crazy-am-i-doing-some), it is not clear where I should call devcontext->Flush? My machine is Win10, nvidia geforce gtx 1060 6GB.

```
const UINT32 default_width = 1280;
const UINT32 default_height = 720;

HANDLE  _shared_handle = nullptr;

std::mutex _acquire_mtx;
INT64   _acquire_seq = 0;

HRESULT CopyResourceHelper(ID3D11DeviceContext* devcontext, IDXGIKeyedMutex* km, ID3D11Texture2D* dst_texture, ID3D11Texture2D* src_texture)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    INT64 release_key = 0;

    do
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_acquire_mtx);
        hr = km->AcquireSync(_acquire_seq, 10);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return hr;
        }
        if (hr == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        }
        if (hr == WAIT_ABANDONED)
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(WAIT_ABANDONED);
        }
        *release_key = ++_acquire_seq;
    } while (FALSE);

    devcontext->CopyResource(dst_texture, src_texture);

    km->ReleaseSync(release_key);

    return hr;
}

class CProducerThread
{
public:
    CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain>         _swap_chain;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device>           _device;
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>    _devcontext;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>        _back_texture;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>        _shared_texture;

    HRESULT OnInit()
    {
        ...
        HRESULT hr = _swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&_back_texture);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

        hr = CreateTextureHelper(_deivice, default_width, default_height, D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX, &_shared_texture);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

        _shared_handle = GetSharedHandleHelper(_shared_texture);    //ID3D11Texture2D -> IDXGIResource -> GetSharedHandle
        ...
    }
    HRESULT OnRender()
    {
        _devcontext->OMSetRenderTargets(...);
        _devcontext->ClearRenderTargetView(...);
        ...
        HRESULT hr = _swap_chain->Present(0, 0);
        ...
    }
    HRESULT OnTimer()
    {
        ...
        CComPtr<IDXGIKeyedMutex> km;
        HRESULT hr = _shared_texture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIKeyedMutex), (void**)&km);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

        hr = CopyResourceHelper(_devcontext, km, _shared_texture, _back_texture);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
        ...
    }
}

class CConsumerThread
{
public:
    CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain>         _swap_chain;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device>           _device;
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>    _devcontext;
    CTextureDrawer                  _texture_draw;  //Includes related objects for rendering textures, reference [Tutorial 5: Texturing][1]

    HRESULT OnInit()
    {
        ...
        HRESULT hr = _texture_draw.Create_ID3D11Texture2D(_device, default_width, default_height);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
        ...
    }
    HRESULT OnRender()
    {
        _devcontext->OMSetRenderTargets(...);
        _devcontext->ClearRenderTargetView(...);

        _texture_draw.Render();
        ...
        HRESULT hr = _swap_chain->Present(0, 0);
        ...
    }
    HRESULT OnTimer()
    {
        ...
        CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>        temp_texture;
        HRESULT hr = _device->OpenSharedResource(_shared_handle, IID_PPV_ARGS(&temp_texture));  //!!! video memory leak
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

        CComPtr<IDXGIKeyedMutex> km;
        HRESULT hr = temp_texture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIKeyedMutex), (void**)&km);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

        hr = CopyResourceHelper(_devcontext, km, _texture_draw.Get_ID3D11Texture2D(), temp_texture);
        RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
        ...
        Invalidate();  //Refresh Window
    }
}
```

Comment: Direct3D 11 does deferred resource destruction, so typically that's done with ``Present``. Can you confirm you are only calling ``GetSharedHandle`` once at init time?

Comment: You should also try ``OpenSharedResource1`` / ``D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE`` which has more sensible semantics. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_1/nf-d3d11_1-id3d11device1-opensharedresource1).

Comment: yes, i only call GetSharedHandle once at init time, and call OpenSharedResource every time. I’m not sure Whether Win7SP1+KB2670838 (the lowest version we support) supports this flag D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE(The official documentation says: not supported until Direct3D 11.1). In addition, I see the obs source code, there is no such flag bit, but it works normally

Comment: KB2760838 adds DIrectX 11.1, so that should work fine.

Comment: After preliminary testing, OpenSharedResource1(D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE) will trigger the continuous increase of video memory

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/daktronics/d3d-9211, this question is similar. If you use OpenSharedResource to get textures every time instead of caching them to textures_, you will see a continuous increase in video memory in the task manager, that is, a video memory leak occurs. Is this a bug in the directx library or a bug in the program that is not properly set?